# How does one Fourier transform an array of 1's and 0's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I'm trying to Fourier transform a matrix of 0's with a solid circle (like a pinhole) of 1's using Python. I am trying to get an image of an Airy Function, which should look like concentric circular ripples viewed from above. I'm still a bit of a beginner with Python and coding more generally.

```
import numpy as np
dimension = 256

list1 = []
listpiece = []

for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension):
        listpiece.append(0)
    list1.append(listpiece)
    listpiece = []

k=128
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension):
        if (i-k)*(i-k) + (j-k)*(j-k) <= 64*2:
            list1[i][j] = 1

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse as sparse

plt.spy(list1)
plt.show()
```

Which gave this image [of a black circle on a white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KGc8.png).
I then converted this list to a `numpy` array.

```
singledimlist = []
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension):
        singledimlist.append(list1[i][j])

prefourierline = np.array( singledimlist )
shape = ( dimension, dimension )
prefourier = prefourierline.reshape( shape )
print(prefourier)
plt.spy(prefourier)
plt.show()
```

Which gave an identical image:

Using `np.fft.fft2` gave a blank image, even though the output had very large changes:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
fouriered = np.fft.fft2(prefourier)
plt.spy(fouriered)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[[ 405.        +0.00000000e+00j -401.08038516-1.50697234e-16j
   389.47420686-2.31615451e-15j ... -370.63201656-5.88988318e-15j
   389.47420686+2.35778788e-15j -401.08038516+8.95615360e-15j]
 [-401.08038516-2.27306384e-15j  397.18553235-1.77932604e-15j
  -385.65292606-1.63119926e-15j ...  366.93100304+7.84568423e-15j
  -385.65292606-2.13934425e-15j  397.18553235-1.08069809e-14j]
 [ 389.47420686+8.66313300e-15j -385.65292606-1.67296339e-14j
   374.33891021+6.30297134e-15j ... -355.97430091-1.40810576e-14j
   374.33891021+1.25700186e-14j -385.65292606-1.24588719e-14j]
 ...
 [-370.63201656-4.69963986e-14j  366.93100304+4.87944288e-14j
  -355.97430091-4.69561772e-14j ...  338.1937218 +3.81585557e-14j
  -355.97430091-4.67444422e-14j  366.93100304+3.64531853e-14j]
 [ 389.47420686+3.34933421e-14j -385.65292606-2.70693599e-14j
   374.33891021+3.08443590e-14j ... -355.97430091-3.30709228e-14j
   374.33891021+2.07603249e-14j -385.65292606-2.63513116e-14j]
 [-401.08038516-5.83528175e-14j  397.18553235+7.09535468e-14j
  -385.65292606-5.72142574e-14j ...  366.93100304+7.01916155e-14j
  -385.65292606-6.12008707e-14j  397.18553235+6.47498390e-14j]]
```

So, I tried using `np.fft.fft`, but fared little better, instead of a blank image, I output a black horizontal stripe with the same width as the radius of the original circle, bisecting the white background.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
fouriered = np.fft.fft(prefourier)
plt.spy(fouriered)
plt.show()
```

I suspect the main problem lies between my computer screen and my chair.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? How does one Fourier transform an array of this sort?

Thanks, I'd be grateful for some help,

ES

Comment: The problem is in the display. Show the magnitude, and scale it appropriately for display. Also: note that the FFT uses the top-left pixel as the origin, so you are computing the transform of a shifted disk. The magnitude will not be affected, but the phase will. Use `ifftshift` to turn your input into an unshifted disk.

Comment: `ifftshift` puts one quadrant in each of the four corners. Doing it twice reverses the process.

Comment: Also, I tried dividing by the largest number (405) to rescale, but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things, so I just provided a working example, that uses numpy. The zeroes and ones question is not a problem, since those are legitimate floating point numbers too, so the physics is fine. There are two issues in finding the right answer in the output. One is to zoom in or, alternatively, make the circle very small. Play with that and calculate the expected ring sizes from the close form solution (Airy-Function).
The other is contrast. Below I just used a log to visualize better. Alternatives would be to take a root. Also note that I didn't square the result (as physics would indicate, i.e. intensity vs electric field).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p 
import numpy as np

n=1000
aa=np.ones((n,n))
x=np.linspace(-1,1,n)  
y=np.linspace(-1,1,n)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)    #this allows us to use vectorized approach, no for loops
R = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)


aa[R<0.1]=0


p.figure(figsize=(20,6))
p.subplot(131)
p.imshow(aa)
p.colorbar()

p.subplot(132)
spec= np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(aa)) 
p.imshow( np.log(np.abs(spec)))
p.colorbar() 
p.title('airy func too fine to see')

p.subplot(133)

p.imshow(  np.log(np.abs(spec[450:550,450:550])))
p.colorbar()
p.title('zoomed in');
```

[image]

Comment: The vectorised approach optimises it even further. This answers it, thanks.